# insert into where ORACLE TOAD

Tags: oracle, triggers

Using a trigger I am trying to update the SOLD column (on the STOCK table) when a record is inserted into the SOLDITEMS table, which matches the BARCODE entered with the existing BARCODE on the STOCK table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCOTT.stock_after_sold AFTER INSERT ON SCOTT.solditems

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
b SCOTT.solditems.barcode%type;

BEGIN
update SCOTT.stock set sold = :new.quantity where b = stock.barcode;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sold successfully inserted into stock table');

END stock_after_sold;
/
```

This doesn't update the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This row

```
b SCOTT.solditems.barcode%type;
```

only declares the property, but you do not initialize it with any value, so this row

```
update SCOTT.stock set sold = :new.quantity where b = stock.barcode;
```

compares  stock.barcode with uninitialized value.

You don't need b, write the update row like this:

```
update SCOTT.stock set sold = :new.quantity where :new.barcode = stock.barcode;
```

Comment: How else can I write this code? I have also tried:          CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCOTT.STOCK_AFTER_SOLD AFTER INSERT ON SCOTT.solditems
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
sold SCOTT.stock.sold%type;
BEGIN
update stock set sold = (select :new.quantity from solditems where solditems.barcode = stock.barcode);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sold successfully inserted into stock table');
END stock_after_sold;
/